# Regular Functional Algorithms

Tags: computer-science, computability, regular-language

A language is [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) if it is accepted by a read-only Turing machine.  I am curious about applying this model to functional problems rather than decision problems.

**Definition:** A *functional read-only Turing machine* is a read-only Turing machine with a generic HALT state (but no ACCEPT or REJECT states).  On input $x$, it returns an integer between $1$ and $|x|+1$ (where $|x|$ is the length of the bit representation of $x$), corresponding to the bit of the input on which the machine halted (or $|x|+1$ if the machine halted on the string of blanks off to the right of the input).

**Definition:** A *regular function* is a function accepted by a functional read-only Turing machine.

Now, my questions:

> 1. Have regular functions been studied before?  If so, do they have a name in the literature?  What is known about them?
> 2. Regular languages have a very nice analytic characterization (that is, they are the closure of the singleton languages under union, composition, and Kleene star).  Is there a similar characterization for the regular functional languages?

Thanks for reading!

---

A good example of a regular function is the problem of locating a substring within the input.  For example, suppose we want to output the index of the first substring "01" within the input on a binary TM (or indicate that no such substring exists, by returning $|x| + 1$).  We implement with the following read-only functional TM:

[image: read-only functional TM]

Where S is the start state, H is the halting state, and X, Y are additional states.  This machine will always halt with its tape head positioned over the 0 in the first "01" substring, which "returns" the index of that substring.

Comment: How is the output computed? Could you give some example?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec and I'll draw up a diagram.

Comment: @dtldarek: all done.  I hope that clears things up.

Comment: If the output can be unary, then this is a special case of a thing called a [transducer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer). For a binary output, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful.  It looks like "rational function" is a keyword I might need.  I'll start reading up.